# python hist2d is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a 2d histogram with python. I found following example on the matplotlib wiki

```
from pylab import *
x = randn(1000)
y = randn(1000)+5

#normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
hist2d(x,y,bins=40)
show()
```

But i get the error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./hist2d_demo.py", line 9,
> in <module>
>     hist2d(x,y,bins=40) NameError: name 'hist2d' is not defined
```

Anyone has an idea how i can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I just copypasted your code sample in my python 2.7.6 and it works perfectly.
I also have numpy 1.8.0, scipy 0.9.0 and matplotlib 1.3.0 installed. 
Your version of matplotlib may be too old, check it this way :

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__
```

Comment: true i have matplotlib 1.1.1rc, i don't found minimal version for hist2d. But i try to install the new matplotlib

Comment: Must be that. Give it a try, and if not working, let me know.